# QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice in VS Release mode

Tags: c++, qt, dll

When I use VS2015 with Qt to run program in Release mode, I receive an error:

> Program:E:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.3\bin\QtCored4.dll
>   Module:4.8.3
>   File:global\qglobal.cpp
>   Line:2246
>   QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice
>   (Press Retry to debug the application)

Moreover, the program should link QtCore4.dll rather than QtCored4.dll, but I don't know why the program alway linked QtCored4.dll.

However, in debug mode the program runs just fine.

The code is as follows:

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);  
GPURenderingApp w;  
w.showMaximized();  
return a.exec();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved, I need link the release version of QVTK.dll instead of the debug version of QVTK.dll